# C++11 cregex_iterator valgrind errors

Tags: regex, c++11, gcc

I compiled the following small program with gcc 6.3.0 ('g++ -std=c++11'):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *cstr = "abc def.ghi";
    regex r(R"(abc|\w+\.ghi)");
    for (cregex_iterator it(cstr, cstr + strlen(cstr), r); it != cregex_iterator{}; it++)
    {
        cout << (*it).str() << endl;
    }
}
```

The program output is fine. However, valgrind reports errors:

Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

at 0x10DF98: std::__cxx11::regex_iterator >::operator==(std::__cxx11::regex_iterator > const&) const (in a.out)

by 0x10D796: std::__cxx11::regex_iterator >::operator!=(std::__cxx11::regex_iterator > const&) const (in a.out)

by 0x10C75C: main (in a.out)

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Check with https://ideone.com/KFbV1D.

Comment: Seems to work on C++14 https://ideone.com/bj8w4C

Comment: You should add the exact commands to compile and link the program.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The sregex_iterator doesn't cause valgrind errors in gcc 6.3.0, however I want to use the cregex_iterator.
I tried with gcc 7.3.0 and this works.
`g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
valgrind ./a.out
abc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
def.ghi
ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts`

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet which uses the cregex_iterator class runs without valgrind errors when compiled with GCC 7.
Thank you for showing interest in this topic.